# Dataset shows an "All" Key when it contains a List of Associations

Tags: bugs, output-formatting, dataset

From a process I have a `Dataset` similar to this minimal example.

```
asscList = {{<|"v1" -> 6, "v2" -> Null|>}, {<|"v1" -> 3, "v2" -> Null|>}};
data = <|"N" -> 1, "V" -> asscList|>;
ds1 = Dataset[<|"A" -> data, "B" -> data|>]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As can be seen above, `Dataset` has added an `All` key and moved the subkeys under this key. The unused area beneath this is greyed.

The `Dataset` is usable so I think it is just a formatting issue.

```
ds1["A", "V", 1, 1, "v1"]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
ds1["A", "V", All, 1, "v1"] // Normal
```

> ```
> {6, 3}
> ```

If the `Null`s are removed then it does remove the `All` key but still has a greyed area to the along the right-hand side.  Also, the subkeys no longer display in the header.

```
asscList2 = {{<|"v1" -> 6, "v2" -> 4|>}, {<|"v1" -> 3, "v2" -> 5|>}};
data2 = <|"N" -> 1, "V" -> asscList2|>;
ds2 = Dataset[<|"A" -> data2, "B" -> data2|>]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the `All` needs to be seen I would expect it under the `"V"` key. Is there a way to have `ds1` display as `ds2`?  It is not ideal but it is a better presentation.

version 11.1 on Win 7 Ent

CASE:3892468

Comment: @gwr Same occurs with `Missing[]`.

Comment: The `All` does seem logical, since you are using a list of a list of associations, so there is somehow a key missing on that level.

Comment: @gwr I agree but it is in the wrong position and has no details under it.

Comment: I have deleted my answer. While the behavior is disappointing, there are some ways to tackle this imo: For queries everything should work as expected and I would follow WReach's advice to not wrap the structure in a `Dataset`. For Display a workaround may be to `Inactivate[ asscList ]`, which can always be removed by `Activate`.

Comment: Take out the extra parentheses: `asscList = {<|"v1" -> 6, "v2" -> Null|>, <|"v1" -> 3, "v2" -> Null|>}`

Comment: @alancalvitti There are no extra parentheses. Key `"V" ` holds a list of lists of associations. The above represents a minimal example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Edmund, I meant the inner parentheses from your example: `{{<|"v1" -> 6, "v2" -> 4|>}, {<|"v1" -> 3, "v2" -> 5|>}}`.  Since an  `Association` can be treated as a sort of list I don't see the need to wrap each association in its own list (as opposed to the outer list)

Comment: @alancalvitti Those are not extra parentheses. The actual dataset has multiple associations in the sub-lists.  The above is a minimal example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Edmund, I figured that but there is no point to the parentheses wrapping an individual association, ie {<|"a"->1,"b"->2|>}. Once removed, `Dataset` has a better chance of rendering as desired.

Comment: @alancalvitti You are not understanding that in the actual case there are more than one association in the sublist. `{{<||> ..} ..}`

Comment: @Edmund, then this is sub-minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean to do this:

```
asscList = <|<|"v1" -> 6, "v2" -> Null|>, <|"v1" -> 3,"v2" -> Null|>|>;
data = <|"N" -> 1, "V" -> asscList|>; 
ds1 = Dataset[<|"A" -> data, "B" -> data|>]
```

[image]

Comment: Nope.  I mean the values of `"V"` a `List` of `List`s of `Associations`.  The list in the OP is the simplest example to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In V12.2 this seems to be improved, a little:

```
asscList = {{<|"v1" -> 6, "v2" -> Null|>}, {<|"v1" -> 3, 
     "v2" -> Null|>}};
data = <|"N" -> 1, "V" -> asscList|>;
ds1 = Dataset[<|"A" -> data, "B" -> data|>]
```

[image]

It says columns 1-2 of **3**, but click the next/advance buttons does nothing.  It does not show the `"v1"` and `"v2"` keys either.

Answer (score 0):

Further exploration the answer looks like something like this based on the question and exploration above leaving out the Null

```
asscList2 = {{<|"v1" -> 6, "v2" -> 4|>}, {<|"v1" -> 3, "v2" -> 5|>}};
data2 = <|"N" -> 1, "V" -> asscList2|>;
ds2 = Dataset[<|"A" -> data2, "B" -> data2|>]
```

> [image]

Extending Naming A and B with C and D you get

```
data3 = <|"A" -> <|"N" -> 1, "v1" -> 6, "v2" -> 4|>,
"B" -> <|"N" -> 1, "v1" -> 3, "v2" -> 5|>,
<|"C" -> <|"N" -> 1, "v1" -> 6, "v2" -> 4|>,
<|"D" -> <|"N" -> 1, "v1" -> 3, "v2" -> 5|>|>|>|>
ds3 = Dataset[data3]
```

> [image: ds3]

Is that the idea?